# Find DB in a geometry problem.

Tags: geometry

$$\bigtriangleup ABC \sim \bigtriangleup ACD$$

Find:

a. AD
   b. DB

$$\begin{align}\frac{AB}{AC} = \frac{CB}{DC} &\quad\to\quad \frac{x}{12} = \frac{9}{6} \\&\quad\to\quad \frac{108}{6} \\[4pt]&\quad\to\quad {x = 18} \end{align}$$

This means, ${AB = 18, AC = 12, CB = 9, DC = 6}$

The missing lengths are ${AD, DB}$

The book says ${DB = AB - AD}$, which they say, is ${DB = 18 - 8 = 10}$

How did they find the 8?

Comment: I don't really understand where *any* of the numbers are coming from. What exactly is given?

Comment: Without a diagram, this is pretty much incomprehensible. (You can insert images into your questions.)

Comment: How do I insert images?

Comment: re inserting images: See [this Meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/how-do-i-upload-an-image-for-use-in-a-question)

Comment: re I'm on a Iphone, so I basically can't do it. Thank you, anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean that $D$ lies on $AB$ and $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle ACD$. $AC = 12, CB = 9, DC = 6$ is known.

You have determined $AB=18$. In a similar fashion, $AD$ can be determined, i.e.
$$\frac{AD}{AC}=\frac{AC}{AB}\implies\frac{AD}{12}=\frac{12}{18}=\frac23\implies AD=8.$$

And thus $DB=AB-AD=18-8=10$.

Comment: Would ${DB}$, be $\frac{DB}{CB} = \frac{CB}{AD}$?

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: DB is part of AB. CB is the right leg, AD is the other Part of AB, AC is the left leg, and DC is the height

Comment: I still don't know what theorem you are using. Moreover, by numerical calculation $\frac{DB}{CB} = \frac{CB}{AD}$ is not true.